# App name not showing up on settings > iCloud > iCloud drive

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

When I navigate to Settings > iCloud > iCloud Drive on simulator my app icon appears, but does not show text/title of the app. How to set it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `iOS Simulator` -> `Reset Content and Settings...`

Comment: no luck, stil blank. it's blank on my iphone too. maybe some field is empty in xcode settings?

Comment: There is a parameter in InfoPlist.strings file CFBundleDisplayName = "Your App Name"; but I'm not sure if it help you

Comment: thanks, it seems that updated the name under my icon on the home screen, but still showing blank in settings / icloud